# Rearranging specific lines of text, based on a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, fasta

I have a FASTA file, in which the headers inside (the lines starting with ">") are not in the right order. What I want to do, is to take part of the text with a certain pattern (`ctg.*,`) and move it to the start of the text. for example:

```
head seq.fasta -n 3
>JACEFZ010000001.1 Cepaea nemoralis isolate C981 ctg35418, whole genome shotgun sequence
cctcctcctccctcctcccctttttCCCTccttcccctttcccccctcctcttcctccccccctcctcccccccctcctc
cttcctccgccctctcctcctcctcactcctcctcctccctcctcctcctccctctacctcctacccCCTCCTCCCGTCA
```

And I want to "move" the `ctg35418` string to the start, where now the new file will be:

```
>ctg35418 JACEFZ010000001.1 Cepaea nemoralis isolate C981, whole genome shotgun sequence
cctcctcctccctcctcccctttttCCCTccttcccctttcccccctcctcttcctccccccctcctcccccccctcctc
cttcctccgccctctcctcctcctcactcctcctcctccctcctcctcctccctctacctcctacccCCTCCTCCCGTCA
```

Well, I'm kind of new with shell scripting, so I did something like this:

```bash
while read line; do if [[ $line =~ ">" ]]; then 
 id=$(echo $line | grep -oe "ctg.*," | sed 's/,//g')
 line2=$(echo $line | sed 's/>//g' | sed "s| ${id}||g")
 sed -i "s|$line|>${id} ${line2}|g" seq.fasta
 fi
 done < seq.fasta
```

I would love to get your inputs to reduce the complexity of the, lets call it, code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `sed` command should do the job:

```
sed 's/>\(.*\)[[:blank:]]\(ctg[^,]*\)/>\2 \1/' seq.fasta > newseq.fasta
```

The `\(.*\)` captures the text between `>` and blank just before `ctg` (both exclusive) and `\(ctg[^,]*\)` captures the text between `ctg` (inclusive) and `,` (exclusive). In the given sample, `\(.*\)` captures `ACEFZ010000001.1 Cepaea nemoralis isolate C981` and `\(ctg[^,]*\)` captures `ctg35418`.

Comment: Thank you. It appears so simple! However, can you please explain me how the string was separated to the two parts?

Comment: @TalZaquin Added a brief explanation.

Comment: Again, Thank you! Will try to play with it a bit to figure it out.